# If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, does $\sigma(n^2)/q$ divide $2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of the divisors* of $x$.  A number $X$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(X) = 2X$.  Denote the *abundancy index* $\sigma(X)/X$ by $I(X)$.

If $N$ is *odd* and perfect, then $N$ can be written in the Eulerian form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

Here is my question:

> If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, does $\sigma(n^2)/q$ divide $2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$?

**Context (as requested by [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39174))**

Since $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is perfect, we have
$$2{q^k}{n^2} = 2N = \sigma(N) = \sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2).$$

Now write $\sigma(q^k)$ as
$$\sigma(q^k) = q^k + \sigma(q^{k-1})$$
so that
$${q^k}\left(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\right) = \sigma(q^{k-1})\sigma(n^2).$$
Since $\gcd\left(q,\sigma(q^{k-1})\right) = 1$, then $q \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

Consequently, we obtain
$$I(q^{k-1}) = \frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(n^2)/q}.$$

Thus, if $k \geq  5$,
$$1 < \frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(n^2)/q} = I(q^{k-1}) < \frac{5}{4}$$
so that $\sigma(n^2)/q \nmid \left(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\right)$.

By the contrapositive, $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid \left(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\right)$ implies the *Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture* that $k = 1$.

Observe that $k = 1$ implies that
$$1 = I(1) = I(q^{k-1}) = \frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(n^2)/q}$$
so that $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid \left(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\right)$.

Thus, the biconditional 
$$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \sigma(n^2)/q \mid \left(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)\right)$$
holds, as already pointed out by Hagen von Eitzen in his answer.

Comment: At least I can't think of a counterexample right now ... So how come you suspect this to hold? Can you give some context?

Comment: Hold on, @HagenvonEitzen.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\sigma(n^2)$ is a multiple of $ \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}$, the desired claim is equivalent to $\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\mid 2n^2$.
We have $2q^kn^2=\sigma(N)=(1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^k)\sigma(n^2)$, hence 
$$ \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=\frac{2n^2q^{k-1}}{1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^k}$$
and we ask whether 
$$\frac{1+q+q^2+\ldots+q^k}{q^{k-1}}=q+1+q^{-1}+\ldots+q^{1-k}$$
is an integer.
Quite apparently, this is the case if and only $k=1$.

Comment: $\sigma(n^2)/q$ is always odd, so you can just say "the desired claim is equivalent to $\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \mid n^2$".  The rest of your answer remains valid.